# What is the role of genera in the development of complex-oriented cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, math-history

I am reading about *complex-orientable cohomology theories* for the first time, *elliptic cohomology theories* in particular.

An inconsistency(?) in the literature is the explicit reference to *genera*. Some references define and use the term, see for instance:

- Graeme Segal's survey, "Elliptic Cohomology."
- Charles Rezk's lecture notes for elliptic cohomology.
- Novikov's paper introducing the ANSS apparently uses genera (although I have trouble reading this paper.)

Yet several make no mention of it, for instance:

- Mike Hopkin's COCTALOS lecture notes.
- Haynes Miller's (Co)bordism lecture notes.
- Doug Ravenel's *Complex cobordism and stable homotopy groups of spheres*.

My understanding of even the topics foundational to this subject area is sparse (working on it!), which is making it hard to see why we ought to pick out and give a special name to these homomorphisms. Which brings me to my question:

> What is the role of genera in the development of complex-oriented cohomology?

And why the hot-cold nature of genera's presence in literature? My impression is that genera are somehow related to the geometric/physical story of elliptic cohomology, and that perhaps(?) homotopy theorists just don't need all that. But that's speculation.

I'd especially appreciate an answer that provides historical context.

Comment: FWIW The Wikipedia page on [Kodaira dimension](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_dimension) has a section on plurigenera.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I think the term OP is referring to is different from the genera that involve handles or differential forms; rather it's a different usage as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence